# systemd: Failed to make us a subreaper: Invalid argument. SSH

Tags: ssh, debian, syslog, systemd, debian-jessie

Since upgrading to Debian 8 (Jessie) which brought in systemd I'm getting the title of this post in my syslog errors.

### Remote ssh login begins

```
10:33:51 pap1 systemd[1]: Starting user-0.slice.
10:33:51 pap1 systemd[1]: Created slice user-0.slice.
10:33:51 pap1 systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 0...
10:33:51 pap1 systemd[1]: Starting Session 23 of user root.
10:33:51 pap1 systemd[1]: Started Session 23 of user root.
10:33:51 pap1 systemd[12228]: Failed to make us a subreaper: Invalid argument
10:33:51 pap1 systemd[12228]: Perhaps the kernel version is too old (< 3.4?)
10:33:51 pap1 systemd[12228]: Starting Paths.
10:33:51 pap1 systemd[12228]: Reached target Paths.
10:33:51 pap1 systemd[12228]: Starting Timers.
10:33:51 pap1 systemd[12228]: Reached target Timers.
10:33:51 pap1 systemd[12228]: Starting Sockets.
10:33:51 pap1 systemd[12228]: Reached target Sockets.
10:33:51 pap1 systemd[12228]: Starting Basic System.
10:33:51 pap1 systemd[12228]: Reached target Basic System.
10:33:51 pap1 systemd[12228]: Starting Default.
10:33:51 pap1 systemd[12228]: Reached target Default.
10:33:51 pap1 systemd[12228]: Startup finished in 19ms.
10:33:51 pap1 systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 0.
```

The client connects as normal, no errors client-end.

### Now after exiting remote ssh client...

```
10:33:55 pap1 systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 0...
10:33:55 pap1 systemd[12228]: Stopping Default.
10:33:55 pap1 systemd[12228]: Stopped target Default.
10:33:55 pap1 systemd[12228]: Stopping Basic System.
10:33:55 pap1 systemd[12228]: Stopped target Basic System.
10:33:55 pap1 systemd[12228]: Stopping Paths.
10:33:55 pap1 systemd[12228]: Stopped target Paths.
10:33:55 pap1 systemd[12228]: Stopping Timers.
10:33:55 pap1 systemd[12228]: Stopped target Timers.
10:33:55 pap1 systemd[12228]: Stopping Sockets.
10:33:55 pap1 systemd[12228]: Stopped target Sockets.
10:33:55 pap1 systemd[12228]: Starting Shutdown.
10:33:55 pap1 systemd[12228]: Reached target Shutdown.
10:33:55 pap1 systemd[12228]: Starting Exit the Session...
10:33:55 pap1 systemd[12228]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 12248 (kill).
10:33:55 pap1 systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 0.
10:33:55 pap1 systemd[1]: Stopping user-0.slice.
10:33:55 pap1 systemd[1]: Removed slice user-0.slice.
```

## System details

The kernel I'm running is the current stock Debian one, 3.16.0-4-686-pae (i.e. >3.4).

Any ideas what this problem is, whether it's serious, and what I can to to stop it?

Comment: You're running a 32-bit system?!?

Comment: oh thank you! yes, the client IS 32 bit (yes, it's old, that's what happens when you work for charity), and it's the client's kernel version I've reported; checked the server's and that is 3.2! Doh. Who'd have thought you need molly-guard on `uname`! Thanks, expect that's where to go to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is on the next line of the log output:

`10:33:51 pap1 systemd[12228]: Failed to make us a subreaper: Invalid argument
10:33:51 pap1 systemd[12228]: Perhaps the kernel version is too old (< 3.4?)`

Your kernel is too old.